# Evaluating a double integral using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the double integral by converting to polar coordinates:
>   $$\int_0^2 \int_0^x \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \, dy \, dx + \int_2^{2\sqrt{2}} \int_o^{\sqrt{8 - x^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \, dy \, dx $$

What I have done: First, I tackled the left hand integral. Using the fact that $x = r \cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$, I converted the left hand integral to $\int r^2 \, dr \, d\theta$. I drew the graph of the region to get a right triangle. I am having trouble determining the limits of integration for $r$ and $\theta$

Comment: @E.H.E: I don't think there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two regions together form a sector of a circle with radius $\sqrt8$ centred at the origin, so the corresponding integral in polar coordinates is

$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi4} \, \mathrm d\phi\int_0^\sqrt8r \, \mathrm dr \,  r\;.
$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha also gave me ~5.91 which I obtained with this method $\checkmark$